# How to handle json error in loop or stop it

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have the following code that populates a `UITableView`. The `end` var holds the number of items in the JSON response. I concatenate variable `n` with the counter `i`. My problem is that in this case the JSON response carries only two items, `Request1` and `Request2`. When the counter reaches 3 the app crashes because there is no `Request3`. How can I change my loop to stop when the condition `counter > end` is met?

```
  let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                var end = jsonData!["num"]!
                var i = 0
                var n = "Request"
                for item in jsonData! {
                    i++
                    n = "Request"+String(i)
                    var result = jsonData![n] as? NSDictionary
                        if let Name = result!["Name"] as? String
                        {
                                Names.append(Name)
                                print(Name)

                        }
                        if let Date = result!["Request_Id"] as? String
                        {


                            Dates.append(Date)
                            print(Date)
                        }


                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                var end = jsonData!["num"]!
                var i = 0
                var n = "Request"
                for item in jsonData! {
                    i++

                    // This should do it
                    if i == end {
                            break;
                    }

                    n = "Request"+String(i)
                    var result = jsonData![n] as? NSDictionary
                        if let Name = result!["Name"] as? String
                        {
                                Names.append(Name)
                                print(Name)

                        }
                        if let Date = result!["Request_Id"] as? String
                        {


                            Dates.append(Date)
                            print(Date)
                        }


                }
```

I'm assuming that by `counter > end` you mean `i > end`, as it's what seems to make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your counter i with 1 rather than 0 incrementing it at the end of the loop like this:

```
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            var end = jsonData!["num"]!
            var i = 0
            var n = "Request"
            for item in jsonData! {
                i++;
                if(i==end)break;
                n = "Request"+String(i)
                var result = jsonData![n] as? NSDictionary
                    if let Name = result!["Name"] as? String
                    {
                            Names.append(Name)
                            print(Name)

                    }
                    if let Date = result!["Request_Id"] as? String
                    {


                        Dates.append(Date)
                        print(Date)
                    }




            }
```

Also you can consider the following way of doing it

```
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            var end = jsonData!["num"]!
            var i = 0
            var n = "Request"
            while(i<end) { //since we are iterating on the basis on the number and specific hardcoded keys of jsondata (and not item)  we can just use a normal while loop
                i++;
                n = "Request"+String(i)
                var result = jsonData![n] as? NSDictionary
                    if let Name = result!["Name"] as? String
                    {
                            Names.append(Name)
                            print(Name)

                    }
                    if let Date = result!["Request_Id"] as? String
                    {


                        Dates.append(Date)
                        print(Date)
                    }




            }
```